# How to implement ngx-infinite-scroll with rest api - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, infinite-scroll

I am new to infinite scroll I am trying to implement ngx-infinite-scroll in angular. I am fetching data from a rest API and showing it in the template

I have tried many solutions on the internet but I am not getting any results. Any help is welcome.

my HTML file looks like this

```html
<app-deal-selection (isGridView)="homeLayoutChange($event)" (selectedDealType)="changeDealType($event)">
</app-deal-selection>

<div infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="2" [infiniteScrollThrottle]="50"  (scrolled)="onScrollDown($event)" 
(scrolledUp)="onScrollUp($event)"
  [ngClass]="{'dc-grid-container': gridLayout === true}">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let deal of dealList">
    <app-deal-info class="dc-grid" [gridClass]="gridLayout" [dealInfoParam]="deal" [dealType]="pageType">
    </app-deal-info>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

and ts file is like this -

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import {ApiService} from '../api.service';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { SessionService } from '../session.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-deal-list',
  templateUrl: './deal-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./deal-list.component.scss']
})
export class DealListComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() pageType: string = "deals";
  @Input() categoryType?: string;
  dealType: string = '';
  dealList: any[] = [];  

  @Input() subType?: string;
  @Input() gridLayout?: boolean;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private sessionService: SessionService, private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: any): void {
    if (this.pageType !== "stores" ) {
      this.getLatestDealList();  
    }    
  }
  
  isGridLayout() {
    return this.gridLayout === true ? true: false;
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.isUserDetailAvailble.subscribe( x => {
      if (x) {
        this.apiService.getUserVoteStats().subscribe(x => {    
          this.sessionService.userSpecific = x.results;
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        }); 
      }
    });  
  }

  homeLayoutChange(event: boolean){
    this.gridLayout = event;     
  } 

  getLatestDealList() {
    let url = 'deals/';
    if (this.pageType === "freebies") {
      url = "/tags/"+ this.pageType + "/";
    } else if (this.pageType) {
      url = "/" + this.pageType + "/";
    } else if (this.categoryType) {
      url = "/tags/"+ this.categoryType + "/";
    }
    
    this.apiService.getDealList(url).subscribe( x => {
      if (x.results && x.results.generic) {
        this.dealList = x.results.generic;
      } else {
        this.dealList = x.results;
      }            
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  changeDealType(event: any) {
    this.dealType = event;
    console.log(this.dealType);
    this.apiService.getDealSelection(this.dealType).subscribe(response =>{
      this.dealList = response.results
    })
  }

  onScrollDown(ev:any){

  }
  onScrollUp(ev:any){

  }
}
```

here is the API service method which is fetching data from the backend

```js
  getDealList(relativeUrl: string): Observable<any> {    
    return this.http.get(this.prefix + relativeUrl);
  }
```

Comment: Here is an example of `ngx-infinite-scroll` called https://github.com/orizens/echoes-player. They are accessing the youtube api. Please note that there is an ngrx dependency to deal with

Comment: @naveen can you please name the component in which they have implemented ngx-infinite-scroll

Comment: As mentioned, its ngrx and it may be difficult to follow. You could use, https://blog.openreplay.com/infinite-scrolling-in-angular/

Answer (score 0):

Add paging kind of mechanism into you api, how much data you need to fetch while scroll down and On `(scrolled)="onScrollDown($event)"` you need to push your result into `dealList`.

Comment: Can you please show me code for this